# IntelliJ inline cpp code in custom language

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I'm making an IntelliJ IDEA plugin to support my custom language that includes inline C++ code (like asm in C code). 
For example

```
$ENTRY Go {
    = <Main <ArgList>>;
}

%%
void f() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        printf("%i = 0x%x\n", i);
}
%%
```

Lines 1-3 are my custom language syntax and lines 4-9 are C++.

I have implemented highlighting, autocomplete, etc. for my custom language, but I want to implement the same for the C++ code inside "%%" "%%". Show me the correct way to support C++ highlighting in my plugin.

Maybe I can somehow use existing plugins [like this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/1373-c-c-) inside my plugin. But I do not know if it possible to implement this.

Comment: Look up "inject language reference", maybe that's what you want? Although that may be a bit too manual..

Comment: You could use the existing plug-in with language injections. Note that it's very limited and unsupported (and may be incompatible with current versions) and there is no first-class C/C++ support for IntelliJ IDEA at the moment (like the one in CLion and AppCode), related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4141.